How to set a remote image to a menu item using a coil3.x
I want to use a remote image as an icon in bottomnavigation.
coil version is 3.0.4
To set an image to a menu item, it must be a drawable class, but when coil was updated to version 3, it changed to return the Image interface.
fun loadMenuIcon(position: Int, imageUrl: String){

    val imageLoader = Application().newImageLoader(mContext)
    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(mContext)
        .data(imageUrl)
        .crossfade(true)
        .target { drawable ->
            val menuItem = bottomNavView.menu.getItem(position)
            menuItem.icon = drawable }
        .build()
    imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}

Type Mismatched
required: Drawable?
found: Image
I got an error.
Is that possible with coil 3.x version? If not, can you recommend another way?
Help me!
